# Unable to login with google using auth0 sdk on custom login page

Tags: javascript, auth0

I have write my own markup login page and with the help of auth0 document I added script which is allowed me to login/signup using email & password. But I'm unable to login with google. I'm not getting where I'm missing something

here is the script

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/9.16/auth0.min.js"></script>;
<script>
    var config = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob("@@config@@"))));

    var params = Object.assign(
        {
            overrides: {
            __tenant: config.auth0Tenant,
            __token_issuer: config.authorizationServer.issuer,
            },
            domain: config.auth0Domain,
            clientID: config.clientID,
            redirectUri: config.callbackURL,
            responseType: "code",
        },
        config.internalOptions
    );

    var webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth(params);
        var databaseConnection = "Username-Password-Authentication";
        var captcha = webAuth.renderCaptcha(
        document.querySelector(".captcha-container")
    );

    function loginWithGoogle() {
        webAuth.authorize(
            {
            connection: "google-oauth2",
            },
            function (err) {
            if (err) displayError(err, loginErrorContainer);
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```